# Построение маршрута для грузовиков

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

В приложении навигатора существует возможность проложить маршрут для грузовика https://yandex.ru/support/navigator/route-cargo.html, возможно ли получать аналогичные данные через JS api?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

[JS API Яндекс Карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/) на текущий момент не поддерживает грузовой маршрутизации. Такую возможность Яндекс оставил только в коммерческих своих продуктах – [Планирование маршрутов](https://yandex.ru/routing/) и [API Маршрутизатора](https://yandex.ru/dev/routing/router).